# How do i do the following in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new to excel so this is quite a simple question. Let's say that I have two numbers, 5 and 10. I want the original number to be 5, but I want to add 10 to it (15) and then add 10 to that answer (25) and then add 10 to that answer (35) and so on. Is there a function or special way of doing this in excel?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Where do you have these numbers? In cells? Or do you need a functionality like a calculator? Where do you need output? In a new cell / overwrite original cell?...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple formula for this:

1) In `A1`, enter your initial value (`5`)

2) In `A2`, enter the following formula:

```
=A1+10
```

3) Once the formula is entered, select cell `A2`, grab the little square at the bottom right hand side of the cell and drag down.